# Windows Phone not accepting DCHP offer

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, dhcp

I'm having an odd problem with my Windows Phone (Lumia 640).

I've been using a Linux server running dhcpd for my DHCP server for a while now and every device I've got in the house is happily getting their IP addresses from it (generally assigned via MAC address so that I know what is on what IP).  However, my Lumia 640 was only intermittently connecting to the network, I went round the houses trying to work out what was going on, and in desperation I turned on my BT HomeHub's DHCP server and all of a sudden the phone would connect (on an IP served by the HomeHub).

My config on the DHCPD server is nothing exciting, and the IP addresses assigned are outside of the subnet so they don't clash with any dynamically assigned addresses.  As I've said I have no troubles with the configuration for multiple devices (android, iOS, MacOS, Linux, Windows, SONOS), it's only the Windows Phone that has any issues.

Any ideas?  Config below...

```
# defaults

ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220, 208.67.222.222;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 192.168.44.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.44.255;
option ntp-servers 192.168.44.254;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.
#
#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

subnet 192.168.44.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    authoritative;
        range 192.168.44.50 192.168.44.79;
        }

# Lumia 640
host russphone {
    hardware ethernet **MAC address here**;
    fixed-address 192.168.44.3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my router (a BT HomeHub 5) was still sending out DHCP offers despite the server being turned off.  Resetting it fixed the problem, not sure why the server was still running, or why certain devices were consistently affected (my phone and my networked printer) and other completely unaffected.